# How to style to_yaml correctly

Tags: ruby, methods, formatting, yaml, to-yaml

I want to store some configuration information about a few apps so I can make an 'app drawer'.  I store the info in an array that looks like this -

```
[["page_view", {"path"=>"somepath/asdf/asdf", "name"=>"Page View"}], ["outage_impact", {"path"=>"newpath/asdf/asdf", "name"=>"Outage Impact"}]]
```

but when I use `to_yaml` on this array I get this output:

```
--- 
- - page_view
  - path: somepath/asdf/asdf
    name: Page View
- - outage_impact
  - path: newpath/asdf/asdf
    name: Outage Impact
```

Ideally I want something more like this:

```
page_view
  path: somepath/af/asdf
  name: blah
outage_impact
  name: blah
  path: adsf/adsf/asdf
```

I tried finding more info on the to_yaml method but it was few and far between.  I think my array might need to be formatted differently but I have been guessing and checking for awhile to no avail.

Should I even be using the to_yaml method at all or would another method work better?

Comment: It seems to be serializing what you have.  You'll need ":" following page_view and output_impact in your expected output.  If you want the latter, could your source data be something like {"page_view": {"path": "somepath/...", ... }, "outage_impact": {...} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting it to a hash and then using `to_yaml` will give a similar output to your example (but with `---` at the start)

```
arr = [["page_view", {"path"=>"somepath/asdf/asdf", "name"=>"Page View"}], ["outage_impact", {"path"=>"newpath/asdf/asdf", "name"=>"Outage Impact"}]]

puts Hash[*arr.flatten].to_yaml
```

gives:

```
---
page_view:
  path: somepath/asdf/asdf
  name: Page View
outage_impact:
  path: newpath/asdf/asdf
  name: Outage Impact
```